# Fetching Multipoint Spatial Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

I didn't find any answer how to select every point in **multipoint** data type in MySQL. I have **multipoint that contains many points** and I want to select every point by **query** and I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Table structure: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBnCa.png)

Example data: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2IE8.png)

In MySQL documentation I've found only this, but it didn't help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fetching-spatial-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL >= 8.0.2, an option may be:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(`p_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
  SET @`sql` := CONCAT('
    WITH RECURSIVE `sequence` AS (
      SELECT 1 `seq`
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `seq` + 1 `seq`
      FROM `sequence`
      WHERE `sequence`.`seq` < ?
    )
    SELECT
      `sequence`.`seq` `id`,
      ST_AsText(ST_GeometryN(`points`, `sequence`.`seq`)) `point`
    FROM `sequence`
      INNER JOIN `tb_test` ON
        `tb_test`.`id` = ', `p_id`);

  SET @`limit` := (
    SELECT
      ST_NumGeometries(`points`)
    FROM
      `tb_test`
    WHERE
      `id` = `p_id`
  );

  PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`sql`;
  EXECUTE `stmt` USING @`limit`;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wh9rWAuLnQjnFX7aFqQu8S/0).

**UPDATE**

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(`p_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
  SET @`sql` := CONCAT('
    WITH RECURSIVE `sequence` AS (
      SELECT 1 `seq`
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `seq` + 1 `seq`
      FROM `sequence`
      WHERE `sequence`.`seq` < ?
    )
    SELECT
      `sequence`.`seq` `id`,
      ST_AsText(ST_GeometryN(`points`, `sequence`.`seq`)) `point`,
      ST_X(ST_GeometryN(`points`, `sequence`.`seq`)) `X`,
      ST_Y(ST_GeometryN(`points`, `sequence`.`seq`)) `Y`
    FROM `sequence`
      INNER JOIN `tb_test` ON
        `tb_test`.`id` = ', `p_id`);

  SET @`limit` := (
    SELECT
      ST_NumGeometries(`points`)
    FROM
      `tb_test`
    WHERE
      `id` = `p_id`
  );

  PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`sql`;
  EXECUTE `stmt` USING @`limit`;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wh9rWAuLnQjnFX7aFqQu8S/1).

Comment: You're amazing, thank you very much. Can I ask how can I get from this selected points separately x and y coordinates (not point)?

Comment: Thank you so much, can you tell me what's the best way to insert multiple points into multipoint by query? Could you advise me where to get information on this topic, I didn't find any useful. Do you think that this is the best way how to store gps coordinates in database (is there better solution)? Thank you so much again!